# $\bigcap_{\alpha}B_{\alpha}$ is the finest $\sigma$-algebra that is coarser than all of the $B_{\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading [Terrence Tao's book on Measure Theory](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf).

On page 102, he states (as an exercise) that if $\{B_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is a collection of $\sigma$-algebras (where possibly $A$ is uncountable), then $\bigcap_{\alpha}B_{\alpha}$ is the finest $\sigma$-algebra that is coarser than all of the $B_{\alpha}$.

I understand that the statement means $\bigcap_{\alpha}B_{\alpha}$ is the largest $\sigma$-algebra contained in all of the $B_{\alpha}$.

Is this just true because any $\sigma$ algebra contained in each of the $B_{\alpha}$ must be contained in $\bigcap_{\alpha}B_{\alpha}$? Or is it more complicated than this?

Comment: yep that's it : )

Comment: @user363464 thank you!

Comment: And the fact that an intersection of $\sigma$-algebras is a $\sigma$-algebra.